# Any way to reference modules/variables from a function?

Tags: python, function, variables

Just to practice a bit of python, I am trying to create a simple game.  I am having a problem creating a function that will take resource from the bank and add it to the player's supply, and vice versa.

I've been able to get success if I hard-code everything, which works, but it's not DRY and requires a lot of code just to do simple addition/subtraction.  Below is the code I have for just two resources, but there are 10-15 resources that will need the same treatment.

Note:  bank is a reference to a module, not an instance of an object, but p is a call to an instance of the Player class.

```
def transfer_resource(receive_or_send, resource_name, qty, player_instance):
    if receive_or_send == "receive":
        if resource_name == "yellow_cake":
            bank.yellow_cake -= qty
            player_instance.yellow_cake += qty
        elif resource_name == "dollars":
            bank.dollars -= qty
            player_instance.dollars += qty
    elif receive_or_send == "send":
        if resource_name == "yellow_cake":
            player_instance.yellow_cake -= qty
            bank.yellow_cake += qty     
        elif resource_name == "dollars":
            player_instance.yellow_cake -= qty
            bank.yellow_cake += qty
```

With the function call like this:

```
transfer_resource("receive", "yellow_cake", 10, p)
```

it would be nice if I could do something like this:

```
def transfer_resource(receive_from, send_to, resource, qty):
    receive_from.resource -= qty
    send_to.resource += qty
```

with a function call like:

```
transfer_resource(bank, p, yellow_cake, 10)
```

Any ideas?  I'm kind of a newbie, so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (`resources` for example) in the bank module and Player class, to store them as `key,value` pair, using the resource like `yellow_cake` and `dollars` as the key and corressponding quantity as value

```py
resources = {"yellow_cake": 10, "dollars": 20}

def transfer_resource(receive_from, send_to, resource, qty):
    receive_from.resources[resource] -= qty
    send_to.resources[resource] += qty

transfer_resource(bank, p, "yellow_cake", 10)
```

Or simply pass the reference of yellow_cake from both bank and p directly (depends on your design)

```py
def transfer_resource(receive_from_resource, send_to_resource, qty):
    receive_from_resource -= qty
    send_to_resource += qty

transfer_resource(bank.yellow_cake, p.yellow_cake, 10)
```

Comment: OMG thanks!  I've been racking my brain to figure this out for a while now, and all it needed was a dictionary.  follow-up question: how come I can call the left side of the dot (p) directly, but it doesn't recognize the variable on the right side ( yellow_cake)?

Comment: not sure to understand your follow-up question. Can you show the code of Player class and how do you call p.yellow_cake ? what's the error you get when you say it doesn't recognize the variable?

Comment: in short, it is not the correct syntax... for a long explanation, i suggest you to start a new question because i am not the expertise to answer

Answer (score 0):

for example, in the Player class, i had this in the **init**:

```
self.yellow_cake = 0
```

and this in the bank module:

```
yellow_cake = 40
```

and when I called this:

```
def transfer_resource(send_from, send_to, resource, qty):
    send_from.resource -= qty
    send_to.resource += qty

transfer_resource(bank, p, yellow_cake, 10)
```

it returns a name error, saying that the name 'bank' is not defined.